# Inconsistent results from the leaks command line tool on mac

Tags: ios, macos, memory-leaks

We are trying to write a tool that would detect any new memory leak added to an iphone app in an automated way. This would basically be a test that would launch the application, run some actions on the app, and then invoke the 'leaks' tool to find out the memory leaks.

Now, the problem is, that when we are launching the app , doing some actions, and running leaks command line tool, we are getting different number of leaks every time. We are making sure that we are doing the same actions on the app, and wait for exactly 'n' seconds before we run 'leaks' tool. However, the total number of leaks that we get varies a lot (from about 120 leaks to 152 leaks).

Does anyone have experience running this tool, and know if its a known issue with this tool? Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be more productive to spend the time to remove the leaks? You could then automate the leaks tool to to assert there are zero leaks.

Comment: :) @NikolaiRuhe thanks for the philosophical lesson.